# how to read the state when starting the software?(UseState and UseEffect)

Tags: sharepoint, react-hooks, hook, sharepoint-online, spfx

** when I start the software for the first time the "items" state property is not set. Not even in setItems.
If I try to reload a second time instead it is valued. How can I change the following code to make the    status value also on first opening?**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bgSP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bgSP.png)

How can I change the following code to make the    status value also on first opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enter code here`I am still learning React Hooks, but I think I see the issue.  In your `useEffect` function, you populate items by calling the `_getItemButton` function, but then you immediately setItems back to an empty array.  Remove the `setItems([]);` statement in the `useEffect` function and see if that fixes the issue.

By including the empty array, the `useEffect` function only runs the first time. Clicking the button runs the `_getItemButton` function again directly, not using the `useEffect` function, so that is why it works the second time.

Hope this helps!